# Why is it important to maintain a readable Git history?

Tags: version-control, git

Every time I read `Merge branch 'origin/master' into master`, or `Oops, forgot to commit changes`, in a Git history, I die a little inside.
Of course I know why it is bad to clutter your history with these types of commits. Mainly because I have worked with both horrible and clean histories, and clean histories are simply better to work with.

But I'm also having trouble coming up with concise and convincing arguments *why* it is a good thing to maintain a clean and readable history, especially when arguing with inexperienced Git users.

So: why Is it important to maintain a clean history in general? Under which circumstances is it especially important?

Comment: "clean histories are simply better to work with" - isn't that a concise argument?

Comment: I think that you should differentiate between your two examples: Merge commits, even with the default message, are fine in a history because they truthfully record the history of development. Rebasing leads to lies, and those lies may break compilability/testability of commits, significantly reducing the value of `git bisect`. `Ooops, forgot to commit changes`, on the other hand, is indeed a sign that the author should have rewritten their history to avoid cluttering the public history with a commit that won't compile/test successfully.

Comment: @cmaster maybe i was imprecise. i didn't mean merge commits per-se. i meant merge commits from *upstream*, that result from a `git pull` when your local branch has diverged. a thing that is very typical and completely unnecessary.

Comment: I mean the exact same commits: What alternatives do you have as the developer wishing to get up to date with `master`? I know only about `git merge` and `git rebase`. And the later creates lies in the history, commits that have likely never been compiled or tested in the form they are recorded in. Correctly rebasing a branch is an ownerous and dangerous process that I would only recommend when working with an svn upstream repo via `git svn`, not when you purely rely on git.

Comment: @cmaster For (relatively short-lived) private feature branches a rebase is not onerous. For these kinds of branches the root is also more or less arbitrary (whatever happens to be the latest code at the time). The intermediate commits won't be the same but they introduce the same diffs and the end result (content-wise) is the same as a merge. The kind of rebase that would be onerous is also the kind of merge that would be onerous and that you're liable to screw up when resolving conflicts by hand. There's nothing particularly dangerous about cleaning up a short segment of private history.

Comment: @Doval That may be true if a feature branch only has to live for a week or two. Unfortunately, there are features that require months of work. And in those cases, frequent merges with upstream are much easier to handle than repeatedly rebasing the whole thing onto the current upstream state. Also, the short-lived feature branch won't include many merges, so I fail to see those merges as a major problem.

Comment: @cmaster That's what I'm saying. The rebases in a short-lived feature branch won't be a major problem either. You're also right that once a branch lives longer than a couple of weeks you're going to have conflicts. However if you did the exact same thing and replaced merges with rebases, you'd get the same conflicts in the same pieces of code at the same times. In my opinion the main issue with rebasing long-lived branches is the fact that you're probably not working on it alone, so you wouldn't be rebasing private history.

Comment: @Doval The problem with rebasing long lived branches is, that you likely need to rebase the first commits several times onto different upstream changes. With the merge approach, you merge with upstream, and then you never need to touch the merged commits again. Even though later upstream work may conflict with some of your early commits, those conflicts are resolved in the merge commits and there is no need to retest your early commits several times. This allows for much more frequent updates from upstream than the rebase approach, where the updates slowly become prohibitively expensive.

Comment: @cmaster Fair point with the increasing costs. I don't rebase long branches anyways because of the shared history issue so I didn't think of it.

Comment: @Doval Unfortunately, I'm forced to: I have to work on big features with an SVN upstream. And I loose quite a bit of time due to those increasing rebasing costs :-(

Answer (score 3):

**In layman's terms:**

- Git history is part of the documentation of the project. Do your project leader tolerate messy documentation?
- It reflects your hard work
- It makes it easy to understand the development history
- All team members can follow progress easyly
- It's easier to trace down problems when something goes wrong
- Saves time when you have to find something
- Makes it easier to understand design choices

Sources:

http://victorlin.me/posts/2013/09/30/keep-a-readable-git-history

http://megakemp.com/2014/08/14/the-importance-of-a-good-looking-history/

Comment: "makes it easy to understand the development history", the question i often get is "why would i even want to understand history?"

Comment: @thrau Which is a really good question. I, for one, want exactly two things: 1. that `git bisect` does not stumble across unbuildable commits, and 2. that I understand the commit that `git bisect` points me at. I won't care what commits came before/after that, `git bisect` sorts that out for me...

Comment: History can explain why changes were made, which can help keep you from needlessly throwing away work done towards some goal.   If I do a refactoring in order to prepare for planned new feature X, but after subsequent discussion X is permanently scrapped, you could consider scrapping my refactoring if it seemed inconvenient for feature Y.

Comment: @thrau *"Those who don't know history are doomed to repeat it"*